# French phonetic dictionary

Tags: dictionary, french, phonetics

I want to be able to search like in a normal dictionary, but a phonetic one. To search words that sounds like I want

Do you know if there's somewhere a file/software/anything that permit to search on a French phonetic dictionary? (idc if it uses international phonetic or whatever phonetic convention as long as I can search for a series of songs)

Answer (score 0):

There is, it's called [lexique](http://www.lexique.org/shiny/lexique/). It's got funny phonetic symbols but they match up to the IPA with a little effort. I've used it extensively with great success, I really like the frequency used data and you can use regex to search fields.